# Writing Tests for Flow and Mortar Apps

Tags: android, unit-testing, mortar, square-flow

I was wondering if there were any examples of writing unit tests for Flow and Mortar Android apps. Part of the advantage of the MVP pattern that it offers the split of the presentation and view logic, and the presentation logic is what you want to write tests against. I was hoping I could see some samples of how people are doing this with Flow & Mortar, and what libraries they are relying on. It'd be great to establish some best practices.

**Edit:** It's worth noting that Google just released [junit support for Android](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support).

Answer (score 3):

There is [u2020-mortar](https://github.com/lemonlabs/u2020-mortar) project which ports u2020 with use of Mortar and Flow. It has some test examples using Espresso.

Comment: Helpful, but I don't see anything about testing the presenter.